# Unable to find "resources/com/sap/ui5.resource.jar " in the SAP UI5 Version 1.56.14

Tags: java, web, servlets, web-applications, sapui5

I'm upgrading my SAP UI5 version in myapplication. 
I have dowloaded all the UI5 from the SAP website. 
When I run the application, it says the Servlet Mapping issue, where I'm not ablet to map to ResourceServelt in the upgrade version 1.56.14

```
<servlet>
   <display-name>ResourceServlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>ResourceServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.sap.ui5.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ResourceServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Can any ono help me with the Resource Mapping in the current version 1.56.14

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that the changelog from the official documentation (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/releasenotes.html) stops at 1.56.12, I would not event try using a 1.56.14 ;)

If you want a newer version either get 1.58.6 or 1.60.2

Comment: Can you help me with the Resource Servlet in the latest Version which you recommended, I dont find the path of the Resource Servlet in the latest version